# Explaining correlation matrix calculations

Tags: r, self-study, correlation, descriptive-statistics

This is the part of my exam preparation. Similar tasks will be provided in my exam paper with extremely limited amount of time. So I need to learn techniques for solving these tasks quickly.

Here is given table showing correlation coefficients for given variables:
[image: Table of correlation coefficients]

So I need to undertake this simple calculation:

[image: What I need to calculate]

1. Regarding (a), do I need to calculate the *expectation value* (?) of (1+ 2*(0.06+-0.11+0.28+1)+3)? And then run calculation?
2. Regarding (b), could I just easily put the command cov() with the given numbers to calculate it?
3. Doing c, how can I implement it in R? Can I load the whole table in a data frame and calculate all the things I need?

Thank you very much in advance.

UPD:

> X, Y, Z: standardised to *0* mean and *1* standard deviation.
>
> Mean of W is *10* and standard deviation of W is *5*.

Comment: Have you perhaps omitted some information?  Correlations are not sufficient to compute what you desire. Do you know what an expected value is?  What a variance is or covariance?  Until you understand these concepts, you will be unsuccessful and likely to not do well on your exam. Your attempts above indicate you have no understanding of these concepts. But I don't think this forum is the right place to teach you such basics.

Comment: Yes I know what do these concepts mean but I just can't understand what the (a) is purposed to calculate within given table. If you can show me how it works on this example (or on another) I would be very respectful to you.

Comment: Can your answers be in terms of E(x), E(w), Var(X), Var(y), Var(w), Var(z)? If you understood the concepts at all, you wouldn't have written 1. and 2. as you did.

Comment: As I said before, I know the principles lying behind e(x), var(x) and etc., but what does the expressions in brackets mean? Its my first time when I study statistics in English so this come unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Then it will work there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve your questions with the information provided. You correlation matrix is:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 \\ 0.35 & 1 \\ 0.17 & -.42 & 1 \\ 0.06 & -.11 & .28 & 1\end{array} \right] $$
To solve your problems, let's define expectations as: $ E\left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \\ w \end{array} \right]  = \left[ \begin{array}{c} \mu_x \\ \mu_y \\ \mu_z \\ \mu_w \end{array} \right] \quad \quad  $

Furthermore, let's call $\sigma_x$ the standard deviation of $x$, $\sigma_y$ the standard deviation of $y$ etc...
The covariance matrix is:
$$ COV\left(\left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \\ w \end{array} \right] \right)  = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \sigma_x^2 \\ 0.35\sigma_y\sigma_x & \sigma_y^2 \\ 0.17\sigma_z\sigma_x & -.42 \sigma_z\sigma_y& \sigma_z^2 \\ 0.06 \sigma_w\sigma_x& -.11\sigma_w\sigma_y & .28\sigma_w\sigma_z & \sigma_w^2\end{array} \right] $$

Your question answers would be (I modified (c) because it was just tedious):

(a) $E\left[ x + 2w + 3\right] = \mu_x + 2 \mu_w + 3$

(b) 
$$\begin{align*} Var(2x+6) - Cov(z + 3y, 2w + 2) &= 4Var(x) - \left(2Cov(z, w) + 6 Cov(y, w) \right)  \\
&= 4\sigma^2_x - 2 \cdot .28\sigma_z\sigma_w-6\left(-.11\sigma_w\sigma_y\right)
\end{align*}$$
(c) 
$$\begin{align*} Var(3x + 2y) &= Cov(3x + 2y, 3x + 2y) \\
&= 9Var(x) + 12Cov(x, y) + 4Var(y) \\
&= 9\sigma_x^2 + 12\cdot.35\sigma_x\sigma_y + 4\sigma_y^2
\end{align*}$$
(d)
$$ \beta = \frac{Cov(x,z)}{Var(x)} = \frac{.17\sigma_z\sigma_x}{\sigma_x^2}$$

It sounds like I would make sure to know:

- [Covariance properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties)
- [Expectation properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties)
- Def of correlation so I can make a covariance matrix from a correlation matrix:
  $$ \rho_{x,y} = Corr(x,y) = \frac{Cov(x, y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y} $$

But of course, I have absolutely no idea what your class is actually about or what's on the exam. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, yes, you are right, I have some extra description. I just updated the post.

Comment: @RLearnsMath As you can see from my calculations, I treated everything not in the correlation table as variables.

Comment: μx is an expression for expectations of x?

Comment: @RLearnsMath yes

Comment: Given the correlation matrix, is the μx the value of 1 itself?

Comment: I'm defining $\mu_x \equiv E[x]$.  From your statement, "X .... standardized to 0 mean" then $\mu_x = 0$. "Mean of W is 10" then $\mu_w = 10$. This has basically nothing to do with the correlation matrix.

Comment: Regrading (c), so I need to do the same thing with Var(z+2w)=Cov(z+2w,z+2w)? Will it be Cov(z+2w,z+2w)=4Var(w)+Var(z)+4Cov(z,w)?

Comment: @RLearnsMath yes

Comment: IF Var(z+2w)=Cov(z+2w,z+2w)=4Var(w)+ 4Cov(z,w)+Var(z)= 4σ2w+4*0.28σZσW +σ2z=4*5^2+4*0.28*1*5+1^2=106.6                         AND                                                                                                 Var(3x+2y)= Cov(3x+2y,3x+2y)= 9Var(x)+12Cov(x,y)+4Var(y)=9σ2x+12*0.35σxσy+4σ2y=9*1+12*0.35*1+4*1^2=17.2 THEN IT WILL BE17.2–106.6=–89.4?